# linux C++, libnoise, getvalue() return value > 1? (reported as bug)

Tags: c++, linux, perlin-noise

I just started to do some tests with `libnoise`, [from the documentation about getvalue()](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/docs/classnoise_1_1module_1_1Perlin.html#a8), this method should return a value from -1 to 1, but the next code ([not so far of this tutorial](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial2.html)) return some values over 1:

```
// g++ test.cc -lnoise#include<iostream>
#include<noise/noise.h>

int main(){
  noise::module::Perlin Ken; // Ken Perlin dat's the guy who developed the noise
                             // I do some noise some time too... more heavy \m/
  int i; // dat's the guys who dev... just kidding...
  int j;
  double dragon; 

  for(j=0;j<100;j++) for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    dragon = Ken.GetValue(double(i)/100.,double(j)/100.,0.5);
    if(dragon>1)std::cout<<"("<<double(i)/100.<<";"<<double(j)/100.<<")= "<<dragon<<std::endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

then I try copy+paste the [tutorial](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial2.html) and change one thing, the point where I want to get the value. Obviously, I use a point where my code return a value over 1, let say : (0.8,0.19,0.5) who gave 1.00101. So,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <noise/noise.h>

using namespace noise;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  module::Perlin myModule;
  double value = myModule.GetValue (0.8, 0.19, 0.50);
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and still returns 1.00101 who's still over 1...
so now, I see nobody complains about that on google & co. so don't know if I mess with something or not, but since I used the tutorial and since the point isn't particular, I think it's not my fault...

(I can still get the max and min and normalize)

I now also opened a bug ticket for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the GradientNoise3D function (noisegen.cpp). The final dot product is multiplied by 2.12, supposedly to bring values to be within the [-1,1] range. However, the correct value should be 0.57735... (1/sqrt(3))

Comment: Could you please explain how you calculated that value? When I edit GradientNoise3D and scale the final dot product by 0.5773502692, the value stays between -1.0 to 1.0 but only uses a small portion of the range (apprx -0.4 to 0.4).

Comment: @Magnus The function calculates a dot product of two vectors: pre-computed gradient and fractional difference. The dot products will be largest when those two are parallel. The fractional vector, a difference of f-[f], is largest when (0.99...,0.99...,0.99...). The gradient is normalized and has length of 1, by definition and to be parallel must have all coordinates equal to sqrt(1/3) or 0.577.. The max dot of these two vectors is approaching 1*0.577.. + 1*0.577.. + 1*0.577.. = 3 * 0.577.. = 1.732.. To normalize, divide by 1.732.. = 0.577... I have no explanation for the magic 2.12 in the code